# Consul and registrator to single host, it's possible?

Tags: docker, consul

i need use consul and registrator for manage multiple docker container to single host, currently i use 
'links" to docker-compose.yml, i would remove links and use consul. I have tested consul and registrator to single host, but the ip assigned is always the same of the node. It's possible that registrator assign the ip of the docker container instead of node ip?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible using the argument `-internal`.

From docs:

> If the argument `-internal` is passed, registrator will register the docker0 internal ip and port instead of the host mapped ones. (etcd, consul, and skydns2 for now). The `-internal` argument must be passed before the `<registry-uri>` argument.

Comment: I have tried with `-internal`, registrator get internal ip but is the same of the consul node, not of container....all container get internal ip of consul node

Comment: I resolved, the problem is the image `progrium/registrator:latest`, the argument `-internal`not work, need use the branch master of github project (described here https://github.com/gliderlabs/registrator/issues/133)